# Changing python string in a list

Tags: python, string, list

I’m trying to replace part of a string from within a list
So far I have this code:

```
newName = 'MeshNew'

list = ['mesh.vtx{12}' 'mesh.vtx{13}']
#print(list) 

for i in (list):
  new = i.split('mesh.vtx')
  print(new)
```

I need it to print out

```
MeshNew.vtx{12},MeshNew.vtx{13}
```

What would be the solution here?

Comment: Do not use list as a variable name

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension:

```
",".join([x.replace("mesh","MeshNew") for x in list])
```

Comment: Thank you for responding I will try this

Comment: Will try this. Than you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

First, in order to properly declare your list you need a comma between the elements. 
Also, a little nit-picky, but try to avoid naming variables keywords (`list` is a keyword).

Then you can just use a replace statement on each element and join them into a string.

```
myList = ['mesh.vtx{12}', 'mesh.vtx{13}']
",".join(x.replace("mesh", "MeshNew") for x in myList])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newName = 'MeshNew'

list = ['mesh.vtx{12}' 'mesh.vtx{13}']
#print(list) 

print ','.join([i.replace('mesh',newName) for i in list])
```

try this method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why do you need to do such replacing, but let's imagine that you have the strings above as templates. In that case I would suggest that you do formatting ([str.format()](https://kite.com/python/docs/__builtin__.str.format)), not replacing.

Here is how would your code look like:

```
new_name = 'MeshNew'

l = ['{name}.vtx{{12}}', '{name}.vtx{{13}}']


formatted = [s.format(name=new_name) for s in l]
print(','.join(formatted))
```

Note that curly braces need to be repeated when using format() function.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using the [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.sub) function:

```
import re

newName = 'MeshNew'
inlist = ['mesh.vtx{12}', 'mesh.vtx{13}']

output = re.sub("mesh",newName, ",".join(inlist))
print(output)
```

Output:

```
MeshNew.vtx{12},MeshNew.vtx{13}
```